# Can pitot tubes be used for unsteady flows?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The classical derivation of the Pitot tube equation assumes that the fluid is in a steady flow to use the Bernoulli equation version for steady flows. But in practice, does Pitot tube can be used also for unsteady flows?

Comment: Yes.  The length scale over which pitot tubes operate is very short, so it is valid to consider the unsteady flow as quasi-steady.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. Unsteady flows (i.e., where the flow velocity changes with time, sometimes quickly) happens all the time in aviation, and pitot tubes are used almost universally to monitor airspeed in planes.

Comment: Thanks. It is because of the approximation of the unsteady flow by a quasi-steady flow as Chet Miller has commented or there is also other reasons?

Comment: it is also because the pitot tube-driven airspeed gauge mechanism itself does a significant amount of pressure "averaging" in its readout.